# GDB: Why can I not print this?

Tags: gdb, debugging

```
(gdb) print argv[1]
$5 = 0xbffffb1d "hello"
(gdb) step
21     sz = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
(gdb) print sz
$6 = 0
(gdb) printf "%s", sz
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) printf "%i", sz
0
```

I am expecting 4 in `sz`, why is it coming out as `0`?

Comment: I think you are stopping at the 21 line and the statement is not executed. And at that point `sz` is **0** which is what you are printing. Type `n` after reaching 21 line and then see what `sz` has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are expecting `4`. You get `5` from `strlen(argv[1])` because `hello` has 5 characters. And then you are adding `1` to it which is why the answer is **6**.

```
sz = strlen(argv[1]) + 1; // 5 + 1 = 6
```

Comment: No, `hello` has **5** characters clearly. `\0` is just a terminating character and is not counted as part of strlen. strlen counts until `\0` is reached.

Comment: @Doug - Sometimes it really happens to me too :)